# Uniqueness quantification in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I'm trying to define the Uniqueness quantification $\exists ! $ in propositional logic. I am aware that it is possible to define it in predicate logic, as the Wikipedia page (and many answers here) shows, but as propositional is weaker, can we define this quantification in propositional? If not, why not?

Comment: I'm not familiar with propositional logic.   Is part of $(\exists x) P(x) \land (\forall y) P(y)  \implies x=y$ not valid in it?

Comment: That's predicate logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no quantifiers in propositional calculus.

Comment: Right. my bad. What about description logic (with no extensions). Would it be possible to formalize something like this?